# Including captcha in a django form

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I'm trying to add Captcha to my Django form. I tried three different libraries but none of them worked for me and i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Here is my last try:

I used [this](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha) library.
My `forms.py` looks like this:

```
class NewUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This is `urls.py`: `path("login/", views.login_request, name="login")`.

This is the frontend: `login.html`: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

I updated my `settings.py` file, so the error must not be there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [django-simple-captcha](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

1. Install it

```sh
pip install  django-simple-captcha
```

2. Add captcha to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings.py
3. Run `python manage.py migrate`
4. Add an entry to your urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns += [
       path(r'captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    ]
```

in forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
    
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

in template:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.captcha }}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. What i want to understand is, what do i need to add to my html file? How do i redirect the form to my login or register pages?

Comment: Just one question: is there a way to add my url pattern with path() instead of url()?

Comment: I tried but it's still not working. For some reason i still can't see the form. I will accept your answer and open a new issue to try to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @c.grey - this works for me. Thank you..do you make be also know how to put a refresh button next to captcha?

Comment: @GKV refer this one => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972515/how-to-create-ajax-refresh-for-django-simple-captcha

Comment: I implemented this as explained in the docs but somehow it allows wrong answers go through validation successfully. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### You can also use a mixin

Have your views inherit from a mixin that validates a recaptcha, c.greys solution is probably easier tbh but you may want to do other things with the request outside the template.

```
import requests
from django.http.response import HttpResponseForbidden
from ipware import get_client_ip

from .settings import RECAPTCHA_KEY, RECAPTCHA_SECRET


class GoogleRecaptchaMixin:
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        g_recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response', None)
        client_ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
        response = requests.post(
            "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
            data={
                "secret": RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
                "response": g_recaptcha_response,
                "remoteip": client_ip
            }
        )
        response_dict = response.json()
        if response_dict.get("success", None):
            return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the same directory as the code above you would have a settings file with your key and secret or you could directly import from django.conf

```
#settings.py
from django.conf import settings


RECAPTCHA_SECRET = getattr(settings, "RECAPTCHA_SECRET", '')
RECAPTCHA_KEY = getattr(settings, "RECAPTCHA_KEY", '')
```

In your template you would have something like:

```
<form id="form-00" method="post" action="/process">{% csrf_token %}
  <button class="g-recaptcha"
          data-sitekey="your recaptcha key"
          data-callback="formSubmit">Recaptcha this</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit(token) {
            document.getElementById("form-00").submit();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey! I'm getting a 'no module named main.settings' module

Comment: in the example I'm importing a local .settings file for the module. Just create a settings file with your recaptcha key and secret. I'll add an example in the answer.

Comment: Ok, i fixed it. But i got the same problem that i'm getting with every other way i tried to make this captcha work. Basically i add the form to my html file but i won't see any form. In this case, i can only see the 'Recaptcha this' button without the actual captcha form. This happens to every other library i tried, i still have no idea why.

Comment: Check the docs on form rendering or manually create the form in your html you could open a new question but you will probably find all you need to know here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/