# Django Simple Captcha Refresh Audio Source

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, captcha

https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha

After following [How to create Ajax refresh for django-simple-captcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972515/how-to-create-ajax-refresh-for-django-simple-captcha/20371801) and getting the captcha to refresh with a Refresh link, how do you refresh the audio src after clicking the Refresh link?

Tried combining this code with the ajax refresh code from the other link above:

```
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.load();
```

Custom_field.html:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% spaceless %}

  <label class="control-label">{{ label }}</label>
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="captcha" class="captcha" />
<br/>
<audio id="audio" class="w-100 mt-2" controls>
  <source id="audioSource" src="{{ audio }}" />
</audio>
      {% include "django/forms/widgets/multiwidget.html" %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Need to add these 2 lines to the rest of the function in the other stackoverflow link for refreshing the image:

```
$.getJSON(url, {}, function(json){

     $("#audioSource").attr("src", json.audio_url);
     $("#audio").get(0).load()

});
```